# Swift Stripe Connect Redirect URI issue

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Basically I am trying to implement Stripe Connect in my app (allowing users to pay to each other) - however, I am experiencing some issues regarding the redirect URI. I have 'connect with stripe button' that basically navigates a UIWebView to the stripe connect URL (with my client_id). However, once the user has either denied or granted access to my platform, how do I retrieve the necessary info? I mean, since I have a web view - what should I put in the redirect URI? How do I retrieve the data that shows if the authorization went well or not? And also - how can I 'access' the specific user?

Connect with Stripe IBAction:

```
 webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&scope=read_write")!))
```

This is really all I have..

I hope I didn't write this too complicated, I have this tendency of making and writing things slightly more complicated than what it is - but this really bothers me - and I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use your secret key to connect a Stripe account, your redirect uri needs to be to your server. Your server will then connect the account, and your server could then redirect to an app uri.

Comment: I read the following in the Stripe docs: "Here’s some sample code for performing the OAuth flow, but we recommend that you use a client library instead of handling the implementation yourself." - does that mean I have to use OAuth2 in my Xcode project?

Comment: for security purposes the oauth part has to actually happen server-side not client side.

Comment: hey @MatthewArkin - Ive stumbled upon tis problem a few years later.. Do you please mind explaining in brief, how exactly do i get a redirect uri to go to my server? Im using Node.Js and iOS client with Firebase cloud functions.. if you see this, id greatly appreciate a response.. Thank you